# Returning Array from a generic cubicEaseInEaseOut function

Tags: java, android, algorithm, android-vibration

I need to create a "waveform" for an Android vibration pattern.  **In doing so, need an array of amplitude values.**  That latter of which I want to create dynamically using a **cubic easeInEaseOut** algorithm (below is a generic function I have been working with).

The duration of the waveform/vibration is 4000ms and amplitude is b/w 0-255.

Can someone help me create this array of amplitude values?

```
easeInOutCubic(t, b, c, d) {
    t /= d/2;
    if (t < 1) return c/2*t*t*t + b;
    t -= 2;
    return c/2*(t*t*t + 2) + b;
}

// t=start time (0?)
// b=start value (0?),
// c=change in value (255?),
// d=duration (4000?)
```

Thanks in advance!